# Getting redirect_uri_mismatch from Google oauth2 from an Azure web app

Tags: google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, maui, azure-webapps

I'm using .net Maui, and I'm using a web API to authenticate users to Google using oauth2.  It works fine in my local environment, but I'm getting a REDIRECT_URI_MISMATCH error from Google when I do it from an Azure domain.  As far as I can tell, the url it's telling me to put is in the console and has been for a few days.

I'm assuming that the url in the error is what should be in the credentials in cloud console?

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/signin-google

[Google Cloud Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoPfD.jpg)

I entered the url from the error into the Google cloud credentials page.  I've seen the other posts on this topic, but they are usually an http vs https thing.

Edit:

There isn't really much in the way of code for this.  At least in the context of the oAuth bit.  I'm using Google's library for oAuth so it's handling showing the page.  And I only have one app set up on Google, so I don't think I could be using the wrong client id and secret.

This does work with localhost, but not with the azurewebsites.net domain.

```
// AuthenticateAsync is case sensitive.
var correctedScheme = await GetAuthenticationSchemeNameAsync(scheme!);

if (correctedScheme == null)
    throw new NotFoundException($"Authentication scheme {scheme} not found");

// Authenticate the user and either create the return url or do the challenge
var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(correctedScheme);

if (!AuthSucceeded(auth))
{
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(correctedScheme);
}
else
{
    // Create the token and redirect back
}
```

...

```
.AddGoogle(o =>
{
    o.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"] ??
        throw new ConfigurationException("Google client ID not set");
    o.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"] ??
        throw new ConfigurationException("Google client secret not set");

    o.SaveTokens = true;
})
```

**Edit #2**

I created a new project with a new key, and that worked.  I'm not sure why.  The original project with the original key worked for localhost.  Maybe you can't have more than one domain in the same project?

Anyways, I figured I'd come back and update this for anyone in the future.

Comment: Can you double check that you put the redirect uri in the correct project.    then edit you question and show me your code

Comment: Can you show the place in the MAUI app where you're using the Web Authenticator ? I think I'm stuck at the same stage.